# Resetting NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

What is the best a quickest way to reset an NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

-[NSMutableArray removeAllObjects] doesn't work for you?

Comment: Stupidly it appears to actually release the object... What is the point in that? Anyway I got round it by putting a [NSMutableArray retain] just before the removeAllObjects.

Comment: Joe - in that case, your code is broken.  See http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html

Comment: its strange that no one has mentioned about just releasing the NSMutableArray and creating a new one. I am really curious as to, given a large number of objects, which one will be faster.

Answer (score 5):

`removeAllObjects`

Answer (score 3):

`removeAllObjects`  if assuming by 'reset', you mean you just want to empty the array.

Answer (score 1):

If you are attempting to do what I think you are attempting to do, which is to keep an array empty but not release it, or at least to make it available next time it is needed then firstly you need to set a variable or a property within your class for this variable:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray;
```

Next add this code before the position at which you will need the empty array:

```
if (!mutableArray) {
              mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
       }
```

Now you can safely call

```
[mutableArray removeAllObjects];
```

without fear that the array will become unavailable once empty.